# What is a "roll call" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-choice, phrase, finnish

I am looking for a word, verb or noun, to describe reading a list of names out loud to figure out who is present.
The Finnish word is "nimenhuuto", and it seems that the English phrase seems to be "roll call".
(Correct me if I'm wrong!)
Is there a Latin phrase for this purpose?
I assume *enumeratio/enuntiatio nominum* would get the point across, but is there a better choice of words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [*delectus, -us*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddelectus2) (also: *dilectus*) usually refers to a kind of choosing or military levy:

> Ibi cognoscit de Clodii caede [de] senatusque consulto certior factus, ut omnes iuniores Italiae coniurarent, delectum tota provincia habere instituit. (Caes. *Gal.* 7.1)
>
> <sup>There he receives intelligence of the death of Clodius; and, being informed of the decree of the senate, [to the effect] that all the youth of Italy should take the military oath, he determined to hold a levy throughout the entire province. (tr. McDevitte)</sup>

However, it can also have the sense of a roll-call:

> ceteri centuriones remissa appellatione ad dilectum oboedienter responderunt. (Liv 42.35)
>
> <sup>The other centurions abandoned their appeal and answered to the roll-call without demur. (tr. Roberts)</sup>

Another possibility with mostly post-classical examples is [*catalogus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=catalogus&la=la#Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=catalogus-contents), "a list of names."

Erasmus uses *catalogus* in his [*Colloquia*, "Euntes in Ludum Literarium"](https://books.google.com/books?id=yzoLQBZMzb8C&pg=PA76) for this:

> Sylvius: Cur adeo curris, Joannes?
> Joannes: Cur lepus, ut ajunt, pro carnibus?
> Sy: Quid hoc proverbii est?
> Jo: Quia nisi adfuero in tempore **ante recitatum catalogum**, actum est de pelle mea.
>
> <sup>...Because unless I am there in time before **the roll is called**, my hide will be in danger!</sup>